How to fit a regression model with the multinomial likelihood?
I am trying to fit a regression model to data that deals with the Multinomial likelihood.
This is an extension of Bioassay where beetles are exposed to a drug, and we are interested in modelling the dose-response relationship.
I am trying to factorize the multinomial likelihood into a product of $2$ binomial likelihoods, in order to fit the model in $\text{R}$ using the $\text{glm}$ function.
Specifically, my set up is as follows.
Beetles are exposed to varying doses of a drug.  At the end of the study, beetles were classified into $3$ groups:
$(1)$ dead;
$(2)$ alive and deformed;
$(3)$ alive and not deformed.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Dose} & \text{No. of Beetles} & \text{Dead} & \text{Alive & Deformed} & \text{Alive & Not Deformed} \\
\hline
18.8 & 16 & 4 & 1 & 11 \\
232.5 & 19 & 8 & 8 & 3 \\
3468.0 & 17 & 10 & 6 & 1 \\
51680.0 & 19 & 17 & 2 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
For the $i\text{-th}$ dose, I have probabilities $\pi_{i1}$, $\pi_{i2}$ and $\pi_{i3}$ where
$\pi_{i1} + \pi_{i2} + \pi_{i3}$ $= 1$.
Therefore, the $y_{ij}$ $($$j = 1, 2, 3$$)$ follow the multinomial distribution with parameters $n_i$ and $\pi_{i1}$, $\pi_{i2}$ and $\pi_{i3}$.
Now my regression model has two parts:
Part $1$ of the model is given by:
$$
\log \left\{ \frac{\pi_{i1}}{\pi_{i2} + \pi_{i3}} \right\} = \alpha_1 + \beta x_i
$$
Here, I have $Y_{i1} \sim \text{Binomial}(n_i, \pi_{i1})$, where $Y_{i1}$ counts the number of deaths (successes) out of the total number of beetles $(n_i)$.
Part $2$ of the model is given by:
$$
\log \left\{ \frac{\pi_{i2}}{\pi_{i3}} \right\} = \alpha_2 + \beta x_i
$$
Here, I have $Y_{i2} \sim \text{Binomial}(y_{i2} + y_{i3}, \frac{\pi_{i2}}{\pi_{i2} + \pi_{i3}})$, where $Y_{i2}$ counts the number of alive & deformed (successes) out of the number of alive beetles (alive $=$ deformed $+$ not deformed).
I worked out the multinomial likelihood, parameterized in terms of the regression coefficients $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and $\beta$.
$$
L = L1 \times L2 = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left[ \binom{n_i}{y_{i1}} \left( \frac{\exp(\alpha_1 + \beta x_i)}{1 + \exp(\alpha_1 + \beta x_i)} \right)^{y_{i1}} \left( \frac{1}{1 + \exp(\alpha_1 + \beta x_i)} \right)^{y_{i2} + y_{i3}} \right]
$$
$$
\times \left[ \binom{y_{i2} + y_{i3}}{y_{i2}} \left( \frac{\exp(\alpha_2 + \beta x_i)}{1 + \exp(\alpha_2 + \beta x_i)} \right)^{y_{i2}} \left( \frac{1}{1 + \exp(\alpha_2 + \beta x_i)} \right)^{y_{i3}} \right]
$$
I can see that the multinomial likelihood can be expressed as a product of $2$ binomial likelihoods.
However, the $2$ binomial likelihoods have a parameter that's common among them, $\beta$.
I want to re-formulate the multinomial likelihood into a product of $2$ terms, where the terms do not have a common parameter.
If I can do that, then each term in the product can be maximized separately.
I will then be able to fit the $2$ parts of the model separately, using the $\text{glm}$ function twice.
Could you please provide any advice on how I can do this?  Any suggestions would be really helpful.  Thank you so much for your time and for any input you could give. Cheers!

Why do you think it's possible to do this?

Thank you so much for your reply!  I'm assuming it's possible to do this because I do not seem to be able to find any other way to fit this model in $\text{R}$ using the $\text{glm}$ function.  I see that the $2$ parts of the model each consider a binomial random variable.  Factorizing the multinomial likelihood into $2$ parts (that do not have a parameter common among them) will allow me to maximize each part separately, and thereby fit the model in R.  If you can provide any input or advice, that would be very helpful.  Thank you once again!

A common approach with ordered outcomes would be a proportional odds model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit

Try the ordinal package in R.
